# Can we use onViewableItemChanged functionality with the scrollview?

Tags: react-native

I need on onViewableItemChanged functionality on scrollview. this prop is availaible on flatlist but not on scrollview! I am having a chat app in react native and for showing chat i had to use scrollview for some reason. but to show the timestamp at that top of chat i need  onViewableItemChanged functionality to achieve this.